# Upload a File and Read Data with FileReader in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

I am trying to create an upload form in Angular 2 ts (2.2.1), that allows the upload of e.g. a CSV file, but instead of the file being sent straight to a http service I want the file first to be validated in the browser.

So far I can already upload a file and print it in the console with this code:

1. Html input for file upload

   ```
   <input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)" #input />
   ```
2. In my angular component I have set up the eventListner and the File reader.

   ```
   export class UploadComponent {

       public fileString;

       constructor() {
           this.fileString;
       }

       changeListener($event): void {
               this.readThis($event.target);
           }

       readThis(inputValue: any): void {
           var file: File = inputValue.files[0];
           var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
           var fileType = inputValue.parentElement.id;
           myReader.onloadend = function (e) {
               //myReader.result is a String of the uploaded file
               console.log(myReader.result);

               //fileString = myReader.result would not work, 
               //because it is not in the scope of the callback
           }

           myReader.readAsText(file);
       }
   }
   ```

This code works perfectly fine so far.

However I have not found a way to store the data from the reader in a way that allows me to access it with my angular component.

The `myReader.onloadend()` callback function does not have access to the component's variables. Is there some way to inject those variables?

How can I get the read data into the `fileString` variable in my component?

Comment: The answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843316/1908296) correct and exact needs for question But I want notify about this answer will give the result of file Reader as binary string not the original string value.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47151035/1908296, if need load the the original CSV file content

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
   console.log(myReader.result);
   this.fileString = myReader.result as string;
};
```

So you can access your variables.

For a more detailed explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: the perfect answer

Comment: according to my linter, however, the result attribute of a FileReader done loading may be an ArrayBuffer OR a string. You should probably prepare for that.

Comment: can you also tell how can i call function from onload function.

Comment: which function? just do: this.myFunction("test");

Comment: @bluppfisk Yes and no. What output you get in `result` is determined by which `readAs...` method you called. Reading the docs for each read-method tells you which it is. So it is 100% safe to cast to string (or ArrayBuffer) *assuming* you know which read-method was used - and in practice this is usually known. Specifically result will be an ArrayBuffer *if* you called [readAsArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer).

Comment: This was what I was looking for.. thanks slaesh :-) was grabbing holes in my haircut attempting to persist result from this.fileReader.addEventListener('load', this.handleEvent); - even looked at ngZones for assistance - pah!

Answer (score 0):

mxii's answer implicitly casts to string, which didn't work for me, maybe with the newer versions of angular it's not allowed anymore.

what did work for me was;

```
JSON.parse(fileReader.result as string)
```

Answer (score 0):

> it work, try like this...

```
this.uploader.uploadAll = () => {
        console.log(this.uploader.queue.length)
        let fileCount: number = this.uploader.queue.length;
        if (fileCount > 0) {
            this.uploader.queue.forEach((val, i) => {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = (e) => {
                    var result = reader.result;
                    console.log(i + '/' + result)
                    this.file64.push(result)
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(val._file);
            }
            );
        }
    }
```