# Angular 4: How to open CSV local file?

Tags: angular, csv, opencsv

I would like to know how to open a CSV file using Angular 4. I found an example on the network, but it is not exactly what I need because in that case the file is downloaded from the server. I need to open the file locally, is it possible?

I found this example:

http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/read-csv-data-using-angular-2.html#.WYNdCnWGNp8

Thanks

Comment: If you mean opening a local (client-side) file from in the web browser see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

you can load files from the client machine using Javascript [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object and (Angular 2+ indeed).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `<input id="preview" type="file" (change)="previewFile($event)" />`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  public previewImage(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      console.log('csv content', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use FileReader() api.have a look at this thread : [Getting Data from FileReader in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843218/getting-data-from-filereader-in-angular-2)

Yes, it is possible like described in the link you provided too
You implement a webservice that will provide you the local file .
your angular applications makes a request to the webservice and retrieve the local file.