# How to read CSV content from url?

Tags: angular

I want to read csv files without upload that particular file. I will give the file url and need to read from there.

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495311/1955268) answer helps you.

Comment: Hi Ashis, the question is fairly incomplete: JavaScript cannot access local file system. Is the Csv file available over the network? What do you mean by "without upload'? You mean uploading the file to a server via a `file` html input? If the file is local to the user's browser, I'm afraid you have no choice. Edit: there is the `FileReader` object, as in the answer linked by @Priyank Panchal

Comment: @A.Chiesa JavaScript cannot access local file system? Tell that to Nodejs File System!

Comment: need to upload without using html input from local

Comment: @callback. Yes, now try to run NodeJS from the browser. ;) Fair enough, from the question it wasn't particularly evident that the context was of a web page, but talking about upload I assumed the Web was the context and a browser the environment.

Answer (score -3):

CSV stands for comma-separated values, and that’s exactly what it is. A plain text file that can be opened by any text editor.

However, a CSV file is a container for database information with one entry per line, and fields separated by commas (or other separators). That’s why it’s useful as a simple data exchange format that can be imported, manipulated and exported by a number of applications, notably spreadsheet processors, XML forms, etc.

Comment: Linking a random answer from Quora (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-open-a-CSV-file-without-Excel) is not a useful answer in any way.